# Forwarding lvalues and rvalues best practice

Tags: c++11

I have a function that constructs an object from its parameters, defined like so:

```
template<class T, class ... Args>
void construct(Args && ... args){
    T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I also have two helper functions that pass into construct.

```
tempalte<class T, class ... Args>
void add(Args && ... args){
    construct<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

tempalte<class T>
void add(T t){
    construct<T>(std::move(t));
}
```

The first overload of `add` is where the I explicitly specify `T` in the call, e.g. via `add<MyType>(1,2,"string");`. In the particular case of a single argument, I want the `T` parameter to be the same as the type of the single argument, so that I don't have to type `<MyType>` explicitly, e.g. `add( existing_MyType_object )`.

The second overload is supposed to take in either an lvalue (in which case it should invoke the copy ctor) or an rvalue (which should invoke the move ctor). My question is, is this the best way to go about doing this? I pass by value for the second overload because I can either copy construct or move construct. I am also wondering if move construction will work correctly if I pass in an rvalue to the second overload, i.e. will the `std::forward` coupled with the `std::move` work as I expect it to.

---

Following some comment advice, I have changed the second overload to look like this:

```
tempalte<class T>
void add(T && t){
    construct<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Comment: I can't really see the question here. *"My question is, is this the best way to go about doing this?"* To do what? You could just delete the second overload and it would improve your code. I think your misunderstanding might be here: *"The first overload of add constructs with parameters"*. Do you think the second overload doesn't *"construct with parameters"*? Perhaps you should expand your question to explain what you think is going on, and why you added the second overload of `add`.

Comment: The second overload allows you to do this `add(t)` instead of `add<T>(t)`.

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry I missed that! However, it would be best to also do that as a perfect-forwarding single-argument function. Anyway, I might edit the question in a few minutes if I can think of a way to make this part of the question more clear

Comment: Imagine a type that is constructed with a single argument, but which isn't a copy/move constructor. e.g. just passing an `int` (the initial size) to `vector<char>`. Do you expect that to be possible through your `add` function? Do you expect `add(5)` and `add<vector<char>>(5)` to build two different things (`int` and `vector<char>` respectively)? I think you need to specify the kind of behaviour you want in single-argument cases like this.

Comment: Yes, they should construct different things. `add(5)` should build an `int`. In reality, the `construct` checks if the `class T` is derived from a base class, but I omitted that for the sake of the question. However, now that you mention it it seems like an important detail.

Comment: Why not pass T&& t and perfect forward, instead of by value, and move?

Comment: My reasoning was since an std::move won't convert an lvalue to an rvalue, and will convert an rvalue to an rvalue, it'll be fine to just move (since I don't care about the cv qualifiers due it being a copy/move construct). If perfect forwarding is the way to go with a copy/move constructor, then I'll do that.